# skip some validations during creation in rails, but have other validations run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to skip the validations of few attributes during creation of a new user like address, pin, phone number etc.
**However**, it still need to do the other validations in the model when user tries to edit it. I tried using :on => :update but that doesn't help me. Any suggestions ?

My Code:

```
validates :address, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }, :on => :update 
validates :city, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }, :on => :update 
validates :state, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }, :on => :update 
validates :zip, :presence => true, :numericality => true, :on => :update, :length => { :is => 5 }
```

Comment: Could you post some code that you have tried? That might help us figure out what the problem is.

Comment: validates :address, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                      :on => :update

  validates :city, :presence => true,
                   :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                   :on => :update
  validates :state, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                    :on => :update
  validates :zip,   :presence => true,
                    :numericality => true,
                    :on => :update,
                    :length => { :is => 5 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates :address, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                      :if => :address_changed?

  validates :city, :presence => true,
                   :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                   :if => :city_changed?

  validates :state, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 50 },
                    :if => :state_changed?

  validates :zip,   :presence => true,
                    :numericality => true,
                    :length => { :is => 5 },
                    :if => :zip_changed?
```

Adding if=> :attribute_changed? will solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

According the the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_presence_of), what you need to do is something like this. Are you saying this is not working?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :address, :on => :update
  validates_presence_of :pin,     :on => :update
end
```

Answer (score 4):

> The validation process on save can be skipped by passing `:validate =>
>   false.`

Note that is there are database constraints you'll still get an error.
e.g. if you use a rails migration and have `:null => false` when it is created (by running the migration) the actual database column will have that restriction be at the database level.  A good thing as validations should be in both places.  The way to override the db constrainst (i.e. you can't) would be a migration to actually remove the constraint.

Comment: @Michale Durrant. By passing false to the save will skip all my validations at creation. I still want to validate few fields during creation.

Comment: Ahh, yes 'a few' didn't jump out.  Let me clarify the question for us, emphasizing that.

Comment: and to stop a lot more answers that missed it like below too.

Answer (score 2):

On creation of record:

```
@model = Model.new(params[:model])
@model.save false
```

This will skip the validation.

Comment: But I still want to validate some attributes during creation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542819/in-rails-3-how-can-i-skip-validation-of-the-password-field-when-im-not-attempt this thread will help you.