# How to get optional fields with form_for using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm using Rails 3.2 and I'm trying to build a form to let a user update its data. However, if the user doesn't want to change its password it can do it by letting the fields blank.

Here is my code for the form :

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :new_password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes" %>  

<% end %>
```

And here is my method update in the users controller:

```
def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

When I'm leaving the password's fields blank, I always get flash messages for incorrect password.

Thank you

---UPDATE---

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :team_id, :updating_password

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence:   true,
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false} 
validates :password, presence: should_validate_password? , length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :password_confirmation, presence: should_validate_password?

def should_validate_password?
    updating_password || new_record?
end 

def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

Comment: Take a look at this SO question, looks similar :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542819/in-rails-3-how-can-i-skip-validation-of-the-password-field-when-im-not-attempt

Comment: Posting your model might be helpful. At least we can see if :password is an ActiveRecord field versus a virtual attribute (attr_accessor). Either way, you should be able to avoid this message if nothing is entered in the field.

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto, yes it's pretty similar but the difference is I want all in one form. I tried to apply the solution given in the other SO question but I failed. I don't know if its the cause but I'm writting : 'validates :password, presence: should_validate_password?, length: { minimum: 6 }' instead of 'validates_presence_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?'

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a really good answer to this question here: [In Rails 3, how can I skip validation of the password field when I'm not attempting to update the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542819/in-rails-3-how-can-i-skip-validation-of-the-password-field-when-im-not-attempt)

I would repeat it, but the given answer is pretty good.  Also points to a railscast on the subject.